# match a string with a whitespace in bash

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have the following string with the following path:

```
#!/bin/bash

FICHERO_MARCADOR="/Users/javier/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks"

cp -p $FICHERO_MARCADOR ./marcadores-google-crome
```

output:

```
+ FICHERO_MARCADOR='/Users/javier/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks'
+ cp -p '/Users/javier/Library/Application\' Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks ./marcadores-google-crome
cp: /Users/javier/Library/Application\: No such file or directory
cp: Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks: No such file or directory
```

Why don't I take the entire route and separate it into two pieces ??? as I do so that I do not separate it since outside the script I access in the following way and it works:

```
ll /Users/javier/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks

-rw-------@ 1 javier  staff   8,2K 21 jul 17:17 /Users/javier/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Analysis

In the troublesome command:

```
cp -p $FICHERO_MARCADOR ./marcadores-google-crome
```

the variable is unquoted. [It should be double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

If you leave a `$variable` unquoted where it should be quoted then nothing in the variable itself will be able to prevent word splitting or filename generation. Neither backslashes in the variable nor quotes therein will matter; nor anything in the variable really. What will matter is the fact the `$variable` before it gets expanded is unquoted.

The space in the string you want to store in the variable should be protected from being interpreted as separator when the variable is defined. You did protect it by double quoting, this idea is good. For comparison: the syntax

```
var=foo bar
```

runs `bar` with `var=foo` in the environment. To store `foo bar` one should either quote:

```
var="foo bar"
# or
var='foo bar'
```

<sup>(in this example it's enough to quote the space only: `var=foo' 'bar`)</sup>

or escape the space:

```
var=foo\ bar
```

Note `var="foo\ bar"` is different, the quotes are enough to protect the space and the quoted backslash gets stored in the variable. (In general a backslash inside double-quotes may or may not be special, it depends on the next character. If the next character is space then the backslash is literal; this is the case here.)

I guess you did

```
FICHERO_MARCADOR="/Users/javier/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks"
```

in a hope the backslash in the variable will protect the space later. As I said, a backslash in a variable is not special for the shell. Your `cp` got more arguments than you had expected.

Your try with `ll` when you literally typed a backslash in the command line worked because this backslash was special. It did not come from a variable. It was as special as the backslash in `var=foo\ bar` mentioned above.

---

#### Solution

To fix your code, protect the space in one way xor the other when assigning to the variable. Then double-quote the variable:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
FICHERO_MARCADOR="/Users/javier/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks"
cp -p "$FICHERO_MARCADOR" ./marcadores-google-crome
```

---

#### Side note

[Avoid uppercase names for variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618). If you get used to them then sooner or later you will possibly change `PATH` or another important environment variable in some script and the rest of the script will fail.